# CSS span formatting

Tags: html, css, formatting

I'm using a lot of span tags on my web site and they all have the same formatting:

```
span {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#404040;
}
```

I need to add a new span tag for text inside a link, but I don't want it to have the same formatting defined above.

Is there a way to **not** apply the formatting above to specific cases that are using span?

Comment: add different Class name and apply different css on that class.

Comment: you can overwrite property with "a span {new styles}"

Comment: You should avoid binding your styles to your html elements, instead your should bind your styles to your classes. The reason for this is that the html elements does not really correlate well to the abstract model of the graphical units you are using in your website, which is going to give you problems when your graphical model is getting more complex. Bind your layout to css-classes that you can, with some experience, organize and structure to suit your graphical model perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a class to overwrite the values you don't want with their defaults, and ensure this rule appears after the one you posted in the stylesheet

CSS

```
span.withoutdefaults {
  color: #000000;
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="withoutdefaults">Text</span>
```

`text-decoration` default value is `none` anyway so you don't need to overwrite that

Answer (score 0):

you can give a particular id or class to span like..

```
<span class="mytext"></span>
```

and follow its css like this..

```
.mytext
{

  color:black;

  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

or whatever styling you want to give it.